# ripple effect on recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ripple

I am using

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

to add ripple effect when items of a recyclerview are touched.
I do display an action bar when an list item is long clicked. However the that item is not highlighted anymore. I used to have a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/selector"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/selector"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

as background in order to highlight the selected item but because I wanted to have the ripple animation I have gone for the selectableItemBackground stuff.
There are some posts here showing how to write a ripple file save in a folder with a 21 file extensions. However the ripple tag is only available  with API Level 21 and above. Since I would like to have a brighter device coverage than just api level 21 and above, I was wandering whether there is another to combine my selector with the ripple stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice trick to solve my problem using FrameLayout.

The layout for recyclerview items looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/modelTitelColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/objects"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_background"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The trick is to set the selector as the background of the inner LinearLayout and to use the famous selectedItemBackground for the view within the FrameLayout.